# Inconsistent loading time for JS and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a PHP script being loaded by JS through JQuery's `$.ajax`.
I measured the execution time of the PHP script using:

```
$start = microtime(); // top most part of code
// all other processes that includes AES decryption
$end = microtime(); // bottom part of code
file_put_contents('LOG.TXT','TIME IT TOOK: '.($end-$start)."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

**It measured somewhere less than 1 second.** There are no prepend/append PHP scripts.

In the JS `$.ajax` code, I have measured the execution time by:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(date('g:i:s a') + ' time received\n');
    // all other processes including AES decryption
    console.log(date('g:i:s a') + ' time processed\n');
}
```

**The time is the same for the time received and the time processed.**

However, when I check the Chrome Developer Tools, **it claims that the PHP script loaded for about 8 seconds**.

What could be wrong in how I measured these things?
I'm certain that PHP is loading fast but how come Chrome reports that it took more than 8 seconds?

I'm using localhost and my web server is fast and this is the only time I encountered this problem. All other AJAX calls are fast.

Comment: Make sure you're using floating point `microtime(true)`, otherwise you're doing arithmetic on strings.  May not be a solution to your problem, but something you may want to take note of.

Comment: That solved it! I spent two hours on this. Could you post your response as answer? So that we can resolve my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PHP section, make sure you're using `microtime(true)` so that you're working with **floating point** numbers instead of **strings**.
Using subtraction on strings may yield incorrect results.

---

Example: http://ideone.com/FWkjF2

```
<?php

// Wrong
$start = microtime();
sleep(3);
$stop  = microtime();
echo ($stop - $start) . PHP_EOL;  // Prints 8.000000000008E-5

// Correct
$start = microtime(true);
sleep(3);
$stop  = microtime(true);
echo ($stop - $start) . PHP_EOL;  // Prints 3.0000791549683

?>
```

Comment: ... and it now returns 8 seconds! Thank you! :)